# how to segment a pdf file by section and content of each section

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

i have a large pdf file( over 500 pages ) and i want to segment it by section and the content of each section

Exemple of the pdf file :

1.1.1 THE STANDARD FOR PROJECT MANAGEMENT

This guide is based on The Standard for Project Management [1]. A standard is a document established by an authority,
custom, or general consent as a model or example. As an American National Standards Institute (ANSI) standard, The
Standard for Project ....

1.1.2 COMMON VOCABULARY

A common vocabulary is an essential element of a professional discipline. The PMI Lexicon of Project Management
Terms [4] provides the foundational professional vocabulary that can be consistently used by organizations, portfolio,
program, and project managers and other project stakeh.....

**i want to substract the big title and the content to a dataframe like shown below**

| title | content |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1.1 THE STANDARD FOR PROJECT MANAGEMENT | This guide is based on The Standard for Project Management [1]. A standard is a document established by an authority.... |
| 1.1.2 COMMON VOCABULARY | A common vocabulary is an essential element of a professional discipline. The PMI Lexicon of Project ManagementTerms [4] provides the foundational... |

And so on

so that I can apply NLP and other text processing

any idea of how i can do this or how to begin ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi! Is your PDF text easily readable by machine (you can copy text to clipboard) or is it PDF which contains images?

Comment: @darthbane426 it contains images

Comment: OK. So i would continue with these steps: 1.) get images from pdf (try google it how to do that with python). 2.) Then you need to use some OCR libraries to get strings from images (google helps too) 3.) When you have strings you can parse them to dataframe - this should be easy if each title starts with numbers or is uppercase

Comment: @darthbane426 thanks for your comment but after text and images substruction do you have any idea or algorithm of how to make that ?

Comment: there should be many examples how to use Google OCR `tesseract` (and Python module `pytesseract`) with PDF files and extracted images.

Comment: every section starts with number like `1.1.1` and upper text - and you could use this fact to detect start of section. when you will have all as string then you can use string's functions for this or regex.